# Obtener datos de un JFrame desde otro

Tags: java, base-de-datos, jframe

tengo un pequeño problema con mi aplicación JFrame. Se trata de una aplicación que guarda datos de unos libros y mi complicación está a la hora de editar esos libros. Tengo un botón para eso, que al pulsar se genera un nuevo JFrame con varios JTextField.
(Tengo una clase llamada book que guarda solamente el titulo y el autor del libro y la instancio como un ArrayList.)
Lo siguiente se ejecuta al pulsar ese botón.

```java
EditarBook editar= new EditarBook(data.get(a));
if (editar.isEditado()){
    data.get(a).setAutor(editar.getLibroEditado().getAutor());
    data.get(a).setTitulo(editar.getLibroEditado().getTitulo());
}
```

En la clase EditarBook tengo varios JTextField y varios métodos:

```java
//Al pulsar el botón de guardar
public void guardar(){
    //T_titulo y T_autor son los JTextField de EditarBook
    b_output= new book(T_titulo.getText(), T_autor.getText());
    editado= true;
    this.dispose();
}
//Devuelve los datos del libro editado
public book getLibroEditado(){
    //b_output es un objeto de la clase book con los datos editados de los JTextField
    return b_output;
}
//Devuelve si se ha editado el libro o si se ha cancelado cerrando la ventana
public boolean isEditado(){
    return editado;
}
```

El problema es que me sale una NullPointerException porque b_output no se ha guardado todavía, pero en realidad sí, porque he pulsado el botón. Qué pasa?
Me gustaría poder pasar todo el código pero es que es bastante...

Comment: Usa el método `hide()` en lugar de `dispose()`, éste último destruye los recursos usados por el componente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es cambiar la forma en que instancias el objeto Book, existe un patrón de programación llamado singleton el cual permite que una clase instancia sea la misma instancia para todos los que lo invoquen, agrega esto a la clase Book:

```
private static book instance = null;

public static book getInstance(){
   if(instance == null){
      instance = new book();
   }
  return instance;
}
```

Ahora en las clases donde necesites manejar esta información solo llama la instancia de esta manera:

Linea de código a Eliminar:

```
b_output= new book(T_titulo.getText(), T_autor.getText());
```

Por esta nueva linea:

```
b_output= book.getInstance();
```

Esos 2 parámetros que usted le enviá por el constructor:

```
 new book(T_titulo.getText(), T_autor.getText());
```

Puede crear un método en la clase book que le reciba esos 2 parámetros y se los pasa para que el actualice el titulo o el autor.

RECUERDA: El nombre de la clase siempre debe empezar con la primera letra en Mayúscula, tu clase no se debería llamar book si no Book, eso forma parte de las buenas practicas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, pero no me ha funcionado. Es mi culpa porque no me expresé bien en la pregunta: me sale NullPointerException al sacar el if al pulsar el botón (el que dice editar.isEditado()), de la otra manera el código no se ejecuta. Creo que cuando se ejecuta esta línea (editar.isEditado()) la ventana continua abierta y por ello no se podrían sacar datos de ella, aunque esto no parezca posible por la ejecución secuencial del código... Gracias igualmente por los consejos.

Comment: La idea del JFrame es disponer de una interfaz y utilizando el patrón MVC se hace mejor el poder utilizar el JFrame, cuando realices el JFrame utilizalo solo de Vista y te creas una clase aparte que seria una instancia Singleton de donde esa vista obtiene la información, en caso que cambies de JFrame la clase que creaste se mantendrá en memoria y si llamas otro JFrame puede acceder a dicha información para que no se pierda.